# Jquery Cookie to hide container for several days when clicked

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am developing a wordpress theme and I am displaying a message both for members and visitors (i check whether someone is a member or a visitor through php). I want to hide the box which includes the message if user click the "close" button for several days (let's say 7 days). Read a lot about cookies (documentation etc) on the web but still can't get this to work so I need some help... Thanks in advance!

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()){
    echo "<div id='wel-msg'>Welcome, registered user! bla bla bla 
                   <div id='closer'>X</div></div>";
    }
    else {
    echo "<div id='wel-msg'>Welcome, visitor! blo blo blo <div id='closer'>X</div></div>";
    };
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, this may help:

There is some sample code on Wordpress that shows how to tell if the user is registered or a visitor:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/tutorial-how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-or-a-visitter

So for example:

```
get_currentuserinfo() ;
global $user_level;
if ($user_level > 0) {
 echo "Welcome visitor"
} else {
 echo "Welcome Member"
}
```

Basically, you want to be using `user_level` instead of `is_user_logged_in` by the looks of it.
Not sure what you want to do with the cookies, but if you say you have been reading about them that shouldn;t be an issue.

Info on setting cookies in PHP:
 -  http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/microtut-getting-and-setting-cookies-with-jquery-php/

for example..

```
if(!cookieSet){
get_currentuserinfo() ;
    global $user_level;
    if ($user_level > 0) {
     echo "Welcome visitor"
    } else {
     echo "Welcome Member"
    }
 //set cookie here
 }
```

Obviously setting cookieSet by checking your cookie somewhere.

Edit:
If you want to hide the wel-msg, then this should be ok:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#closer").click( function() {
    $("#wel-msg").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what I need to do is to hide the welcome message if the user (no matter if he is member or just a visitor) clicks the hide button (#closer in my example).

Comment: @ArgGeo Added a small snippet of JQ that would hide the message on clicking the closer element. Not sure if that's what your after?

Comment: This is not what I wanted to do, I knew that. The problem was on working with cookies. I did this to work. Thank you very much for your answers! :)